# MacBook Pro (13inch, mid 2012) iPhoto photos

Tags: macbook-pro, time-machine, photos, photos.app

I'm getting my MacBook Pro wiped at the end of the year because it's the school's computer. I was wondering if my iPhoto photos on my laptop will be wiped as well? I use Time Machine, so will that help me recover them?

Answer (score 1):

If you've been using Time Machine to backup your MacBook Pro to an external hard drive then yes, your photos will be backed up as long as you haven't specifically excluded them from being backed up.

To check:

1. Go to System Preferences > Time Machine
2. Click on the Options button at bottom right
3. In the window that appears, make sure that your iPhoto Library is not listed and therefore excluded from your backups

As long as it's not listed, you'll be fine.

Another thing you can do is to also manually backup your iPhoto Library. The iPhoto Library is located within your Pictures folder.